# How to make 3D carousel rotate automatically, no clicks required and stop at mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I found this 3D carousel online and wondering how to make it rotate infinitely without clicking buttons and stops at mouse hover, then continues to rotate again when there is no hover.

```
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}
```

[image]

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nopr/pen/rfBJx)

Comment: Can yo add a working snippet? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Hi! This is the link to codepen https://codepen.io/nopr/pen/rfBJx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mamoun othman did a great job here! I added the `hover` pause/restart functionality below:

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"), currdeg  = 0;

function rotate(e){
  currdeg = currdeg - 60
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}

// storing state in window.carouselPause
const startCarousel = (e) => window.carouselPause = setInterval(rotate, 1000);
const stopCarousel = (e) => clearInterval(window.carouselPause);

carousel.on({
  // pause carousel when mouse is over
  'mouseenter': stopCarousel,
  // resume when mouse is off
  'mouseleave': startCarousel
});

// start the carousel when the page is loaded
startCarousel();
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}
.d {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #f26522;
}
.e {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #630460;
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #8c6239;
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 104px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
    <div class="item d">D</div>
    <div class="item e">E</div>
    <div class="item f">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you removed the snippet?

Comment: @Zuber What snippet?

Comment: woking snippet, initially you added working snippet but now its not there

Comment: I edited it - maybe refresh the page? I didn't remove the snippet haha.

Comment: yeah its there.. +1 for your answer. @mamoun othman did a good job but your answer has the `hover` feature too which the questioner need  :)

Comment: I was about to do something similar but I don't have much time, your solution is way better in term of UX too +1 from me!.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want, just used [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to trigger the animation:

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    currdeg  = 0;

setInterval(rotate, 1000);

function rotate(e){
  currdeg = currdeg - 60
  /*if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }*/
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}
.d {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #f26522;
}
.e {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #630460;
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #8c6239;
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 104px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
    <div class="item d">D</div>
    <div class="item e">E</div>
    <div class="item f">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I've been looking for!

Comment: @pan I added a version with the `hover` functionality also.